# Codeignitor URL Conflicts

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, seo

Hello there i am working on web app built with codeignitor where i am suppose to
show the services available withing cities.

For this i am trying to create url like

```
www.abc.com/mumbai-hotels
```

where mumbai is city name and hotels is service to be search within city

Now uptill i have following code in my `routes.php` file

```
$route['(about-us)'] = 'websiteController/aboutus';   
$route['(:any)'] = 'serviceController/info';
```

The first line from routes.php suppose to redirect to `aboutus` action of `webiste controller`.
 And second line is suppose to redirect to info action inside the `serviceController`.

But unfortunately this is not happening, but it creating conflict and in both case it is still
redirecting to service controller.

Does any one have idea what mistake i am making here, and put me on proper track

Comment: remove parenthesis `()` and put only `about-us`

Comment: I have tried removing parenthesis but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose url is like following : www.paintes.com/painters-in-chennai
then route can be like following

```
    $route['painters-in-(:any)'] ='index/paintersIn/$1';
```

in **index.php** controller, i'll be able to receive chennai like following

```
    function paintesIn($city_name)
    {
        echo $city_name //OUTPUT WILL BE "chennai"
    }
```

if url is like www.paintes.com/painters-in-mumbai , then output will be mumbai

as per your request, URL is liek following : www.paintes.com/mumbai-painters
then you can write like following

```
    $route['(:any)-painters'] ='index/paintersIn/$1';
```

Comment: Hello Mac this one is the really nice solution i really appreciate it, is there is another way to bring the city name at the beginning and service after it, because it is the prior requirement of client. Otherwise i will somehow try to go with your solution

Comment: Please check bottom part of the answer, i updated as per your request. please upvote if it's helpful

Comment: Second solution is too good, but my app having lot more service like painter , hotels and many more ( > 500). Thus to avoid over-coding i tried for $route['(:any)-(:any)'] = 'inventory/info';. Where first parenthesis represent city name and second service name. Rest of thing to validate the parenthesis could be possible inside the function of controller. Somehow all these idea came from you answer , thus upvoting it. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this :

```
$route['(:any)-(:any)'] = 'serviceController/info';
```

Comment: Yeah i did it in same way, read my posted comment to @Mac Rathod. Really helpful thanks for sharing...